# Вызов метода, если OnTriggerStay() не нашёл объект

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я имею объект, на котором прикреплён скрипт с OnTriggerStay()

```
private void OnTriggerStay(Collider collision)
    {
        if (collision.tag == "ЗДЕСЬ_ТЭГ")
        {
            //Код...
        }
    }
```

Но он вызывается только когда находит Collider (если не находит, то ничего не делает), а мне нужно, чтобы если не найдёт Collider, то выполнял бы ниже метод (выше писал, что если не находит, то он вообще не выполняет OnTriggerStay())

```
void destroing()
    {

        myScript flColl = GetComponent<myScript>();

        Destroy(flColl);
    }
```

Как мне реализовать это?
Заранее спасибо

Comment: Лучше не использовать Update

Answer (score 0):

```
private bool _inside;
private string _insideTag = "tag";

private void OnTriggerEnter (Collider other) {
    if (_inside == false && collision.tag == _insideTag)
        _inside = true;
}

private void OnTriggerExit (Collider other) {
    if (_inside == true && collision.tag == _insideTag)
        _inside = false;
}

private void Update () {
    if (_inside) {

    } else {

    }
}
```